# A function to read a text file and transfer that information to a dynamic vector

Tags: c, scanf

Create a function to read a text file and transfer their name to a dynamic vector of structures.
I'm reading the file but it doesn't appear nothing on the screen.

```
typedef struct aluno student;
struct aluno{
       
       char name[50], address[50], number[9];
       int year;enter code here

};

student *lerFicheiroTexto(char *nameFile, int *tam){

        FILE *f1;
        student buffer;
        student *aux;
        student *vetor = NULL;
        f1 = fopen(nameFile, "rt");
        if(f1 == NULL){
            printf("Error opening the file text");
            return NULL;
        }

        
        while(fscanf(f1, "%s %s %d %s", buffer.name, buffer.address, &buffer.year, buffer.number) == 3){
               
                printf("%s\t%s\n%d\n%s\n", buffer.name, buffer.address, buffer.year, buffer.number);
                aux = realloc(vetor, sizeof(student)*(*tam+1));
                  if(aux == NULL){
               //realocation failled
               printf("Reallocation failled. Maintain tam \n");
               (*tam) = 0;
               return NULL;
           }
                  else{
                      
                      vetor = aux;
                      vetor[(*tam)] = buffer;
                  
                  }
                
            (*tam)++;
        }
        
        
        fclose(f1);
        return vetor;
}
```

Comment: `== 3`?? There are four format specifiers.

Comment: Even with 4 it doesn't work

Comment: What do you see if you debug the code? That is, run it in a debugger. Where does it fail? What does `fscanf` return (if it gets that far)? There's still quite a bit of basic debugging you can do. If you still need help then please provide the input file data.

Comment: When I debug the code it fails on the screen it appears this message:  Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...

Comment: That's not debugging. That's just running the code. Debugging means tracing thru the code to see what each line is doing and finding out where exactly things start going wrong. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

I would need to have your input file to test this but I changed your code a bit.
I'm also a student so my apologies if I've done something wrong.

From what I see, I believe your code could be improved like so:

Definition of struct:

```
typedef struct aluno {
    char name[50], address[50], number[9];
    int year;
} Aluno;
```

Function to read the file and build your array:

```
Aluno* lerFicheiroTexto(char* nameFile, int tamanho)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(nameFile, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening the file text");
        return NULL;
    }

    Aluno* listaAlunos = malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
    char line[255];
    while (fgets(line, 255, file) != NULL) {
        Aluno currAluno;
        sscanf(line, "%s %s %d %s", currAluno.name, currAluno.address, currAluno.year, currAluno.number);

        listaAlunos[tamanho] = currAluno;

        listaAlunos = realloc(listaAlunos, sizeof(Aluno) * ++tamanho);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return listaAlunos;
}
```